# VB.Net Application + PHP Website both connected to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, vb.net, encryption

Hello :) I have searched all over to see if this is possible, I am looking to build an application in VB.Net and a website in PHP, both being connected to the same MySQL database. I have managed to get basic connectivity working reading, inserting data etc.

The part I am confused about is the security side, with the PHP site I was looking at Sha1 or MD5 salted encryption, and the same with VB.Net, what I'm wondering is if this is possible, whether both will produce the same hash to compare and authenticate?

Any advice would of great help as I'm just learning these languages :)

Comment: You should never use a simple hash function to protect your user's passwords. You need to use a strong hashing scheme like PBKDF2, bcrypt, scrypt and Argon2. Be sure to use a high cost factor/iteration count. It is common to choose the cost so that a single iteration takes at least 100ms. See more: [How to securely hash passwords?](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/211/45523)

Comment: It's not clear who you want to authenticate at which system. The app user at the front-ends or maybe a "secret" account whose credentials are "hidden" in the source code at the database?

Comment: This is just a mock project I'm doing to try to learn more about security and authenticating users using different languages. I have no real users per say just will be testing with made up users. It be a application where most of the data is entered by like staff members, data being customer details, invoices, products, orders. The customers could login on the website check progress of their orders, edit their info. Just a basic system to help with learning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SHA1 and MD5 are not secure for hashing passwords.

Bcrypt is built into PHP via the `password_hash` and `password_verify` functions, there's a C# library here https://github.com/martinsteel/Bcrypt.NET which is compatible with PHP.

Source for more information: https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#csharp